# Run SQL statement at beginning of each DB connection in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-boot, datasource

How can I run a custom SQL statement directly after obtaining a DB connection with Spring Boot?

The SQL needs to be run each time a new connection is established.

The solution should work with the Spring Boot default DataSource implementation (which I think is a Tomcat pooling data source).

It doesn't really matter what the statement is, but in my case it will be `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=xxxx`

Comment: Can't you set the schema to use in your connect string? `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/myschema` [Working with SQL databases §29.1.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database)

Comment: @StephenP unfortunately not, Oracle doesn't support schemas in connection strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tomcat Jdbc Connection pool has a parameter "initSQL"  https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

It looks like you can configure each pool parameter in your .properties file (@see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25573035/280244)

So give a try,

Spring Boot before 1.4:

```
spring.datasource.initSQL=ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=xxxx
```

Spring Boot 1.4 or later:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.initSQL=ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=xxxx
```