# How can i make a init-sql in Spring Boot-1.4.1-RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a spring boot application:

using dependencies:

```
    dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.1.RELEASE")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.4.1.RELEASE')
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.39')
}
```

I want to run sql on init:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'
```

to support emoji read/write

I make these configs on application.properties

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.init-sql=SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'
spring.datasource.init-sql=SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'
spring.datasource.connection-init-sql=SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'
```

But i can't make it work, and there no log for this on application startup.

Comment: Where did you get these init-sql properties from? I can't find any kind of documentation on them.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4.0-M1-Configuration-Changelog

Comment: Listed under the **removed keys**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think i found the answer, according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38794121/1755542):

the right properties will be:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.initSQL=SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'
```

then this will exec on connection.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the related spring-boot [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-database-initialization)

As stated, you need to create a file called `schema.sql`, or `schema-mysql.sql` if the script is mysql specific,  and put your scripts there. Also, make sure that you set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`.

you can read the details in the doc.

Comment: i just want to execute some sql lines: like SET NAMES 'utf8mb4', will this work?

Comment: Should be. schema.sql file is where you put DML scripts.

Answer (score 0):

First you can create configuration bean:

```
@Configuration
public class JdbcConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("db.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

And then add to your `application.yaml`:

```
db:
    datasource:
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        jdbcUrl:
        username:
        password:
        initSQL: "YOUR INIT SQL HERE"
```