# Java Persistence API read unicode JSON column

Tags: java, mysql, json, jpa

I have a localizable/unicode JSON column on a MySQL database which is accessed via JPA. I get garbled up unicode strings on my API response

```
{
   "bannerTitle": "Copyright  Â© 2019",
}
```

The JSON binds to following entity property

```
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "json")
private String settings;
```

My data source URL has the Unicode tags as follows

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?characterEncoding=utf-8&useUnicode=yes
```

I tried using a converter in the following lines

```
public class StringToByteConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, byte[]>
```

which fixed my fetch queries, but my save queries crashed with

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.
```

What is the right way to fix while using the JPA persistence libraries?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
MySQL: 5.7.27
Java: openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
Spring boot : 1.5.6.RELEASE

Comment: hmmm.. my question is more on how to achieve this in a JPA/java level

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.initSQL=SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'
```

One of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48526332/mysql-5-7-20-cannot-create-a-json-value-from-a-string-with-character-set-binar) reproduces the same error you have and solve the same by using `set names utf8mb4`. Way to execute the same in JPA is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527477/how-can-i-make-a-init-sql-in-spring-boot-1-4-1-release)