# How set initial size connection to postgresql in application.yml

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

Always when i connect to my database, I see 10 idle connection. How can I set this in application.yml.

I use spring boot 1.5.6.RELEASE.

It's not working:

```
spring:
   datasource:
    maxActive: 5
    maxIdle: 5
    minIdle: 5
    initialSize: 5
```

When I created @Bean it's working, but I need solution in application.yml

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfig {

    @Value("${dbconfig.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${dbconfig.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${dbconfig.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${dbconfig.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        ds.setUrl(url);
        ds.setUsername(username);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: Which version of spring-boot you are using?

Comment: I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573034/spring-boot-how-do-i-set-jdbc-pool-properties-like-maximum-number-of-connection) will be useful

Comment: @StackOver Please accept the answer if it resolved your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing to say these are `properties`. I think the following will work.

```
spring:
    dataSource:
            properties:
                 maxActive: 5 
                 maxIdle: 5 
                 minIdle: 5 
                 initialSize: 5
```

***Note: If you're using tomcat-jdbc, you have to define it explicitly like,***

```
spring:
    dataSource:
        tomcat:
             max-active: 5 
             max-idle: 5 
             min-idle: 5 
             initial-size: 5
```