# SQLServerDataSource in spring boot app with connection pool

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm trying to set up pooling with `SQLServerDataSource` if i understand this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25573035/1262568

```
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder factory = DataSourceBuilder
            .create(this.properties.getClassLoader())
            .driverClassName(this.properties.getDriverClassName())
            .url(this.properties.getUrl())
            .username(this.properties.getUsername())
            .password(this.properties.getPassword());
    return factory.build();
}
```

Geting connection from a `DataSource` created in that way will return   pooled connection using one of the available connection pools. 
But what if instead `DataSourceBuilder` i want to use `SQLServerDataSource`
Will it also automatically use one of the available connection pool?

```
public DataSource dataSource() {
SQLServerDataSource sqlServerDataSource = new SQLServerDataSource();
        sqlServerDataSource.setUser(UserName);
        sqlServerDataSource.setPassword(Password);
        sqlServerDataSource.setURL(Url);
        return sqlServerDataSource;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it also automatically use one of the available connection pool?

No it won't. `SQLServerDataSource` is a SQL Server (driver) specific class, whereas `DataSourceBuilder` is a Spring class. Only the latter knows about Spring and its configuration and its configured connection pool.

Is there a reason you'd need to use `SQLServerDataSource`?

To access the native connection even from the pool, use

```
SQLServerConnection conn = connection.unwrap(SQLServerConnection.class);
```

just remember to call `close()` on `connection` and not `conn`, so the connection can be returned to the pool.

Comment: I don't know if there is a reason. It's a legacy code, will try to change it.

Comment: With JDBC you almost always use only the interfaces of the specification (`Connection`, `DataSource`, `ResultSet` etc.). Dipping into the actual driver classes is only necessary when you're attempting to do something complicated that cannot be achieved through regular JDBC (i.e. something very database specific).

Comment: because bulkinsert is used connection must be optained from `SQLServerDataSource`

Comment: In that case you should be able to use `connection.unwrap(SQLConnection.class)` (or whatever is the implementing class) to get the native connection where you need it.