# Set properties for DataSource in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have multiple databases in spring boot
One of the configuration for Oracle database is shown

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
 
 
 @Bean 
public DataSource getDataSource() { 
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create(); 
    dataSourceBuilder.username("SA"); 
    dataSourceBuilder.password(""); 
    
    return dataSourceBuilder.build(); 
}
 
@Bean("OracleTemplate")
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate()
{
     return new jdbcTemplate()
}
```

Now i want to set following properties for the Datasource .How can i set it?

```
validationOnquery
 validationQueryTimeout
 minIdle
 maxIdle
 testWhileIdle
```

Comment: This may answer your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573034/spring-boot-how-do-i-set-jdbc-pool-properties-like-maximum-number-of-connection

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning datasource directly, you can store it as:

```
DataSource myDataSource = dataSourceBuilder.build();
myDataSource.minIdle = 0
myDataSource.validationQuery =
```